# How to define a constructor calling a super with optional arguments?

Tags: dart

I would like to extend [Text class which has following constructor](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/text.dart#L199-L206):

```
  const Text(this.data, {
    Key key,
    this.style,
    this.textAlign,
    this.softWrap,
    this.overflow,
    this.textScaleFactor,
    this.maxLines,
  }) : assert(data != null),
       super(key: key);
```

But I have issues with super's optional parameters and syntax. So, what I am trying to do is something like:

```
BlinkingText(data, 
    {key, 
     style, 
     textAlign, 
     softWrap, 
     overflow, 
     textScaleFactor, 
     maxLines}):
             super(data, {key, style, textAlign, softWrap, overflow, textScaleFactor, maxLines});
```

But syntax is wrong. So I wonder how should I deal with optional arguments and if there is a simple way to get a *bunch* of arguments and pass them as I get them to super.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edited: There is now a shorthand for passing all your named arguments to the super-class.

["Super initializers"](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-2-17-b216bfc80c5d) were introduced in Dart 2.17.

You pass named arguments to the super constructor by prefixing the name with `.super`, so:

```dart
    BlinkingText(super.data, 
        {super.key, 
         super.style, 
         super.textAlign, 
         super.softWrap, 
         super.overflow, 
         super.textScaleFactor, 
         super.maxLines})
       : super();
```

The `: super()` can be omitted as usual, that's the default super-constructor invocation, but you can also choose to use a different super-constructor.

Every `super.x` parameter is implicitly forwarded to the super-constructor, as a parameter with the same position or name, and the super-constructor's parameter types and default values are automatically inherited.

Comment: what if superclass has default values? They are not getting applied if any of the args missing, right?

Comment: Then you need to have the same default values in the subclass. If that's not possible, because you can't express the same constant value for some reason, then you're stuck.

Comment: The above example doesn't compile. You'd have to add explicit types to the constructor parameters, eg. `String data, {Key? key, (...)}`. Otherwise, you assign  _dynamic_ type to the super constructor parameter which has already defined type in `Text` class.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up this question, since Dart has since introduced a new feature to solve the problem.